# CGI script error when connecting to sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, cgi

I have the following cgi script which tries to run a python code upon button submit from a user form.

```
   #!home/ann/anaconda2/lib/python2.7

   print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
   print '<html>'
   print '<head>'
   print '<title>First CGI Program</title>'
   print '</head>'
   print '<body>'
   print '<form action="./myfile.py" method="get">'
   print '<p> Click here: <button type="submit">submit</button>'
   print '</form>'
   print '</body>'
   print '</html>'
```

The file which i'm trying to run (myfile.py) is trying to connect to sqlite database. However when I run this code console prints this error and script doesn't execute at all.

```
   File "/home/ann/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line  248, in run_cgi
   os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Any advice on how to solve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think this might be useful for people with similar issues. I made it work by including both

```
      #!usr/bin/env python
      #!home/ann/anaconda2/lib/python2.7
```

at the beginning of my script.